# selector not working after upgrading from jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.8.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

DOM:

```
$(".feed > div:not([feedtype=top]):[isforward]"); // working in 1.4.2
$(".feed > div:not([feedtype=top]):[isforward]"); // not working in 1.8.2
```

I want to select the children of `.feed`, which does not have an attribute `feedtype` equals `top` BUT with an `isforward` attribute.

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: could you also show your html?

Comment: If the first one worked, then this was probably a bug (the second colon just does not make sense there). Just omit it:  `$(".feed > div:not([feedtype=top])[isforward]");` You could also use `div[feedtype!=not]` instead of `:not(...)`.

Comment: @techfoobar Changing the quotes doesn't work :(

Comment: See documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: @FelixKling I am very sorry that I expressed in a totally wrong way. I have updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: @FelixKling When I switched the order it worked. Updated in question

Answer (score 3):

Just chaining attribute selectors should work:

```
$(".feed > div[feedtype!=top][isforward]");
```

The second colon in your selector looks strange to me. Colons are either used for CSS pseudo selectors or jQuery selector extensions. It does not make sense at the position where you have it.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. My fault. But I am very sure it was working with 1.4.2 :)

Comment: Or just remove the second colon without changing the `:not()`.